# rpmbuild differences in RHEL 5.7 and RHEL 6.1

Tags: rhel, rpmbuild

I'm trying to build an RPM using rpmbuild, which would work for both RHEL 5.7 machines and RHEL 6.1 machines, and I'm having some trouble understanding how to structure my rpmbuild/SOURCE directory.

According to what I understood, if my package name is XXX, than I need to prepare rpmbuild/SOURCE/XXX.tar.gz, a tarball which contains:
1. A directory named XXX;
2. In it, all the directories and files I'm installing should be ordered as if their paths are relative to the root directory (i.e. /)

For instance, if I want to install a file called foo.sh to /tmp/XXXdir/, I need to have rpmbuild/SOURCE/XXX.tar.gz contain XXX/tpm/xxxdir/foo.sh

This is what I understood and this is what works when I install my RPM on my RHEL 5.7 machine (i.e. in the example above the file is installaed to /tmp/XXXdir/foo.sh).
However, on an RHEL 6.1 machine I get the undesired behaviour of having my files installed to a newly created /XXX directory, and from there I get the same tree structure I wanted for / (i.e. in the example above I get the file at /XXX/tmp/XXXdir/foo.sh).

Any idea why this happenes? Perhaps I've got it wrong and my rpmbuild/SOURCE structure is not as it should be? Any insights would be very helpful.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Lior